# Reverse axis in python bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, axis

I am trying to reverse the y axis and set range for both x and y in a Bokeh scatter plot. I am using:

```
BokehPlot.bokeh_scatter(data=df, x_range=(min_utc, max_utc), y_range=(min_val, max_val))
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: bokeh_scatter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x_range'
```

Any idea how axes can be reversed in a Bokeh scatterplot with a pandas dataframe input

Comment: There is no function `bokeh_scatter` in all of the Bokeh library. Are you using some wrapper library around Bokeh? Please provide more information, and more complete code.

Comment: Now I feel pretty dumb, I was calling one of my own classes and methods.. I even had the code to set the range in the method. I'll self answer this

Comment: It happens to everyone :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will flip the y-axis for a scatter plot.

```
p = figure()

xmin = data[xval].min()
xmax = data[xval].max()
ymin = data[yval].min()
ymax = data[yval].max()

# Note that ymin and ymax are in reverse order in y_range.
p.scatter(xval, yval, x_range=(xmin, xmax), y_range=(ymax, ymin))
show(p)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't set explicit bounds on your axis, its range will be a [`DataRange1d`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.DataRange1d), with bounds automatically computed from whatever you plot. In this case, setting the range's `flipped` attribute will flip it without requiring you to set explicit bounds:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
fig = figure()
# Do some plotting calls with fig...
fig.y_range.flipped = True
show(fig)
```

If you want to set explicit bounds, see [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29294958/3220880). As Don Smythe's answer mentions, you can set the bounds in reverse order to invert any axis type.