# Invert y-axis values - Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am attempting to create a line graph with an inverted y-axis. The  y-axis I was hoping to create would have a maximum value of 1 (top) and a minimum axis value of 5 (bottom).

I have not been able to find how to perform this operation in the Bokeh documentation.

Any help that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317898/reverse-axis-in-python-bokeh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the default auto-ranging `DataRange1d`, you can set:

```
p.y_range.flipped = True
```

Or if you want to set bounds explicitly, you can when the figure is made:

```
p = figure(..., y_range=(max, min)) # min/max inverted here
```