# Pandas, Bokeh, or using any plotting library for shifting the x-axis for seasonal data (months 7 -> 12 -> 6 or July 01 - June 30)

Tags: pandas, time-series, bokeh, timeserieschart

I want to display seasonal snow data for the seasonal year from July 01 - June 30.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1':['1954-03-20','1955-02-23','1956-01-01','1956-11-21','1958-01-07'],
               'date2':['1954-03-25','1955-02-26','1956-02-11','1956-11-30','1958-01-17']},
              index=['1954','1955','1956','1957','1958'])
```

It is an extension to my previous question [Pandas: Visualizing Changes in Event Dates for Multiple Years using Bokeh or any other plotting library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712333/pandas-visualizing-changes-in-event-dates-for-multiple-years-using-bokeh-or-any)

Scott Boston, in his answer to my comment in that question, suggested using Range1D and modifyng the answer in [How can I accomplish `set_xlim` or `set_ylim` in Bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294957/how-can-i-accomplish-set-xlim-or-set-ylim-in-bokeh).  It works for continuous scalars, but I couldn't get it to work with a discontinuous ranges like [182:366], [1:181].

Adding x_range=Range1d(182, 366) shows me the first half of the seasonal year, but I can't get the second half of the seasonal year (1, 181).

```
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])

df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])

df=df.assign(date2_DOY=df.date2.dt.dayofyear)
df=df.assign(date1_DOY=df.date1.dt.dayofyear)

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import FuncTickFormatter, FixedTicker
p1 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=300,x_range=Range1d(180, 366))

p1.circle(df.date1_DOY,df.index, color='red', legend='Date1')
p1.circle(df.date2_DOY,df.index, color='green', legend='Date2')
p1.xaxis[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks=[1,32,60,91,121,152,182,213,244,274,305,335,366])
p1.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
 var labels = {'1':'Jan',32:'Feb',60:'Mar',91:'Apr',121:'May',152:'Jun',182:'Jul',213:'Aug',244:'Sep',274:'Oct',305:'Nov',335:'Dec',366:'Jan'}
 return labels[tick];
""")
show(p1)

#(Code from Scott's answer to my previous question.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'date1':['1954-03-20','1955-02-23','1956-01-01','1956-11-21','1958-01-07'],
               'date2':['1954-03-25','1955-02-26','1956-02-11','1956-11-30','1958-01-17']},
              index=['1954','1955','1956','1957','1958'])
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])

df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
```

Adjusted mapping day of year to axis starting with Jun 1st.

```
df['date2_DOY_map'] = np.where(df['date2'].dt.dayofyear<151,df['date2'].dt.dayofyear-151+365,df['date2'].dt.dayofyear-151)

df['date1_DOY_map'] = np.where(df['date1'].dt.dayofyear<151,df['date1'].dt.dayofyear-151+365,df['date1'].dt.dayofyear-151)

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
```

Add Range1d import form bokeh.models

```
from bokeh.models import FuncTickFormatter, FixedTicker,Range1d
p1 = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=300,x_range=Range1d(1, 366))

p1.circle(df.date1_DOY_map,df.index, color='red', legend='Date1')
p1.circle(df.date2_DOY_map,df.index, color='green', legend='Date2')
```

Fixed x-ticks and labels to match Jun 1st start

```
p1.xaxis[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks=[1,31,62,93,123,154,184,215,246,274,305,335,366])
p1.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
 var labels = {'1':'Jun',31:'Jul',62:'Aug',93:'Sep',123:'Oct',154:'Nov',184:'Dec',215:'Jan',246:'Feb',274:'Mar',305:'Apr',335:'May',366:'Jun'}
 return labels[tick];
""")
show(p1)
```

[image]

## EDIT (oops I started on the wrong month above)

Pretty easy to fix, we just need to modify the x-axis mapping of dates and redo the ticks and lables.

Use 181 vs 151 because Jul 1st is the 181st day where June 1st was the 151st day.

```
df['date2_DOY_map'] = np.where(df['date2'].dt.dayofyear<181,df['date2'].dt.dayofyear-181+365,df['date2'].dt.dayofyear-181)

df['date1_DOY_map'] = np.where(df['date1'].dt.dayofyear<181,df['date1'].dt.dayofyear-181+365,df['date1'].dt.dayofyear-181)

p1.xaxis[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks=[1,32,63,93,124,154,185,216,244,275,305,336,366])
p1.xaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
 var labels = {'1':'Jul',32:'Aug',63:'Sep',93:'Oct',124:'Nov',154:'Dec',185:'Jan',216:'Feb',244:'Mar',275:'Apr',305:'May',336:'Jun',366:'Jul'}
 return labels[tick];
""")
```