# Move data closer to y-axis

Tags: python, bokeh

I'd like less whitespace to appear between the y-axis and the plotted data. The x_axis is of type datetype. So, x[0] = Timestamp('1840-03-01 00:00:00')

[image]

Oh wise internet, do you know how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294957/how-can-i-accomplish-set-xlim-or-set-ylim-in-bokeh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I accomplish \`set\_xlim\` or \`set\_ylim\` in Bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294957/how-can-i-accomplish-set-xlim-or-set-ylim-in-bokeh)

Comment: I don't think so. That question is about how to set explicit range limits. This one is about how to make auto ranges have less padding.

Answer (score 4):

The (default) auto-ranging `DataRange1d` objects that plots come with have a default [`range_padding`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.DataRange1d.range_padding) that you can change:

```
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.02
```

By default, `range_padding` is interpreted as a percentage of the total range, but you can also set [`range_padding_units`] if you want some fixed, absolute amount of padding.

Alternatively, if you want to set the range `start` and `end` completely explicitly yourself, see [How can I accomplish `set_xlim` or `set_ylim` in Bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294957/how-can-i-accomplish-set-xlim-or-set-ylim-in-bokeh)

Answer (score 0):

Thank-you everyone for your guidance. The suggestion did not work verbatim. Most likely because my knowledge of Python and Bokeh wouldn't fill a box of smarties. However, it got me on the right track which led to this, which works:

```
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.02
```

Comment: No, I simply wrote it out wrong in a hurry. Thanks for pointing it out, I have updated the answer.